# Lie brackets and Derivative operator

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a manifold and $X_1$ and $X_2$ two vector fields over $X$

Prove that: $[f X_1 , X_2 ] = f · [X_1 , X_2 ] − X_2 (f ) · X_1$

where [] is the Lie brakets and $D_{X_2}$ the derivative operator acting
 on $ C^∞ (X, \mathbb{R})$.

I don't really find any clear definition of the derivation operator, morover, [] is bilinear so $[f X_1 , X_2 ] = f · [X_1 , X_2 ]$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're wrong. It's only bilinear over constants, not over functions. And why do you have the title "tensor product ..."? Write $X_2(f)$ for $D_{X_2}(f)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll fix the title. You mean bilinear only over scalars?

Comment: The Lie bracket is bilinear only with respect to the scalars. Indeed, if it was bilinear with respect to the functions, then $[X_1,X_2]$ at point $x$ would only depend on $X_1(x)$ and $X_2(x)$. As for the derivation operator: $X(f)$ at point $x$ is $(d_xf)(X)$. To put it differently: take a path $\gamma$ with origin at $x$ such that $\gamma’(0)=X$. Then $X(f)(x)=(f\circ\gamma)’(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the definition!

Comment: I found the solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788486/problem-in-proving-the-property-of-lie-bracket-of-vector-fields